# How to update array of object using node with mongodb and postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

My Object is

```
{
"_id": "5fc49f48502ed001f437f49b",
"students": [
    {
        "_id": "5fc49f48502ed001f437f49c",
        "name": "John",
        "class: "5",
        "age": "9"
    },
 {
        "_id": "5fc49f48502ed001f437f49d",
        "name": "Richa",
        "class: "7",
        "age": "13"
    }
]
}
```

My Update Code is:

```
router.put("/:id/:studetid", async (req, res) => {
try {
const student= await Student.update(
  { "students._id": req.params.studentid},
  {
    $set: {
      "students.$.name": req.body.name,
      "students.$.class": req.body.class,
      "students.$.age": req.body.age,
    },
  }
);
```

When i Select id and Update any value form object, Value updated success but other value which are not update sets to null..

```
{
"_id": "5fc49f48502ed001f437f49b",
"students": [
    {
        "_id": "5fc49f48502ed001f437f49c",
        "name": null,
        "class: "6",
        "age": null
    },
}
```

Please Can anyone help me to solve this problem...I want to update data dynamically...I'm using Postman to send data

Comment: which module are you using to update mangoDB could you add more details on what librarty you are using

Comment: @PDHide: off-topic - but "mangoDB" would have actually been an awesome name instead of mongoDB haha, now I'm craving for a mango :D

Comment: Let's hope for the best

Answer (score 0):

You had an incorrect variable name in the url.

```
router.put("/:id/:studetid", async (req, res) => {
```

should be

```
router.put("/:id/:studentid", async (req, res) => {
```

This will work

```
await Student.update(
  { "_id": req.params.studentid},
  {
    $set: {
      "name": req.body.name,
      "class": req.body.class,
      "age": req.body.age,
    },
  }
);
```